# JPA Persisting wrong Calendar date

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, jpa

I have a class named Period, which has `initialDate` and `endDate` with `TemporalType=DATE` annotations (Calendar attributes). I am trying to persist it with *JPA*, but apparently *Hibernate* is not managing to do it correctly.

These are the attributes:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataInicial; // initialDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataFinal; // endDate
```

I'm trying to set like this:

```
Periodo periodo = new Periodo();
periodo.setDataInicial(Calendar.getInstance());
Calendar dataFinal = periodo.getDataInicial();
dataFinal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
periodo.setDataFinal(dataFinal);
em.persist(periodo);
```

And it works perfectly fine when I sysout all the values, but in the Database it is recorded as:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | dataFinal  | dataInicial |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  5 | 2017-10-03 | 2017-10-03  |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

If I set `Calendar dataFinal = Calendar.getInstance();` it works correctly and persists as I wanted to:

```
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | dataFinal  | dataInicial |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  6 | 2017-10-03 | 2017-04-03  |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

Why? I think it's more of a Java/OOP problem, so I'll stick with it in the tags.

Comment: `java.util.Calendar` is mutable.  You've assigned the same object to both fields, and then mutated the object.

Comment: What would be the best approach for managing different dates then? I have an initialDate which has user input, but endDate is always 6 months later.

Comment: Why do you need Calendar? Why dont u just use Date?

Comment: It was a development flaw at the start of the project. Now every date handler is a Calendar object. So, is there anyway I can set it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar.getInstance()
```

This returns a instance of Calender

```
periodo.setDataInicial(Calendar.getInstance());
```

this assigns Calender object to `dataInicial` and when you say

```
Calendar dataFinal = periodo.getDataInicial();
```

The Calender object which is reffed by  `dataInicial` is assigned to `dataFinal` . So after this the changes you make either for `dataInicial` or `dataFinal` is reflected in both fields .

There is NO flaw in OOP